# Problem with updating an ENUM type in postgresql and alembic

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, enums, alembic

I have an issue with `ENUM` in postgresql and alembic and I couldn't resolve the problem using the existing topics in the StackOverflow in this regard.

I had the following code:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM
from enum import Enum

class StatusEnum(Enum):
    requested = "requested"
    accepted = "accepted"
    declined = "declined"

class EventModifications(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "event_modifications"

    old_value = Column(Text)
    new_value = Column(Text)
    status = Column(
        ENUM(StatusEnum),
        default=StatusEnum.accepted.value,
        server_default=StatusEnum.accepted.value
    )
```

Then I appended an entity in the Enum class and also changed the default value of `status` column to the new added value:

```py
class StatusEnum(Enum):
    requested = "requested"
    accepted = "accepted"
    declined = "declined"
    modified = "modified"  # new one

class EventModifications(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "event_modifications"

    old_value = Column(Text)
    new_value = Column(Text)
    status = Column(
        ENUM(StatusEnum),
        default=StatusEnum.modified.value,  # changed the defaults
        server_default=StatusEnum.modified.value
    )
```

Error caused by Alembic:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) column "status" cannot be cast automatically to type statusenum
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING status::statusenum".

[SQL: ALTER TABLE event_modifications ALTER COLUMN status TYPE statusenum ]
```

But when I change the name of `StatusEnum` class to something else it works well!

Comment: Can you provide the alembic migration `.py` code too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use these queries to solve your problem

1.

```
ALTER TABLE "event_modifications" DROP "status";
```

2. 

```
DROP TYPE "statusenum"
```

- note that your data will be removed and you need call alembic again to migratation.

Comment: thank you for your response, it fixed my problem temporary, but as you mentioned I lost the data on that column!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called [`alembic-postgresql-enum`](https://pypi.org/project/alembic-postgresql-enum/)

you just have to install and import this library in you migration's env.py file.

```
import alembic_postgresql_enum
```